# Stream Flow Arrow

Tags: qgis, stream

I'm willing to know how to do these kind of arrows in QGIS. I'm trying to estimate "urban rivers" through urban areas and these tool seems to work for the purpose. What tool can do these? Wich other do you suggest?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the `Layer Properties` panel > `Symbology` you find under `all symbols` the `pointing arrow` style, which should work for you. Obviously you can modify this symbology making it more or less similar to what I see in your screenshot.

[image: example]

To avoid having the arrowhead repeat itself at each segment of the line you want to use the style on, uncheck the item: `repeat arrow on each segment`.

[image: example 2]

You will get this effect:

[image: example 3]

In addition I suggest you to look in this repository [https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/](https://www.qgis.org/it/site/), maybe you find something interesting (for example this [water flow style](https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/60/)? )